# How to get product id in product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, template

How to get product ID in `Magento_Catalog/template/view/my_custom_template.phtml` file?

Trying this one:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
```

But not working!

Comment: This is  your custom template `Magento_Catalog/template/view/my_custom_template.phtml`? Where is the layout xml?

Comment: what is the block class you are using to render the template?

Comment: it is a paid theme... I've created a child theme ... and created a custom template... http://prntscr.com/eepvjk

Answer (score 5):

Use block class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` for render your **phtml** file.

You can get **product Id** by below code

```
$block->getProduct()->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

extend or use block class

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\abstractView
```

Get product using $block->getProduct() in your phtml file